# NotImplementedError: this is an abstract class in speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I got some code from google for speech recognition when i try to run that code i'm getting "NotImplementedError" please see the below code and help me.I'm using Mac.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Recognizer() as source:
print("Speak Anything")
audio = r.listen(source)

try:    
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("you said:{}".format(text))
except NotImplementedError:
    print("Sorry could not recognise your voice")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 4, in 
    with sr.Recognizer() as source:

File "/Users/chiku/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py", line 51, in **enter**
    raise NotImplementedError("this is an abstract class")

NotImplementedError: this is an abstract class

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 4, in 
    with sr.Recognizer() as source:

File "/Users/chiku/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py", line 51, in **enter**
    raise NotImplementedError("this is an abstract class")

NotImplementedError: this is an abstract class

Comment: Maybe you should speak w/ whomever you got this code from?

Answer (score 1):

In the line above, you instantiate a `Recognizer` object, then you try to use the uninstatiated class in the problem line. Should that be

```
with r as source:
    ...
```

Comment: Error is from this line:
with sr.Recognizer() as source:
... ... audio = r.listen(source)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    ... audio = r.listen(source)
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: That's not the same error, that's a different error. That error is because you didn;t indent the block under `with ...as source:`

Comment: issue resolved. After initiating microphone issue resolved.
mic = sr.Microphone()
with mic as source:

Answer (score 0):

I have the below code and it gives me same error i.e

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/../Listen.py", line 25, in 
print(Listen())
^^^^^^^^

File "/Users/../Listen.py", line 8, in Listen
with sr.Recognizer() as source:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py", line 51, in **enter**
raise NotImplementedError("this is an abstract class")
NotImplementedError: this is an abstract class

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from googletrans import Translator


def Listen():
r = sr.Microphone()

with sr.Recognizer() as source:
    print("Listening...")
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)
    
try:
    print("Recognizing...")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='hi')
    
except:
    
    return ""

query = str(query).lower()
return query
    
    
Listen()
```